# Return Table from Store Procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get table data which is being returned from Stored procedure.

```
Create procedure Proc1
as 
begin
Select * from Employee
End
Go
```

I want to use this as :

```
Select * from Departments D
inner join (Exec proc1) p
on D.Emp_id = p.Emp_id
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: although you cant have stored procedure directly pull out a table. i am guessing the reason you will want to use a stored procedure is to pass parameters. You can actually use a table-valued function.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you can't. Stored procedures cannot be used as a source of data in a query.

The best you can do is put the results of the stored procedure into a (temporary) table and then query that:

```
create table #sprocResult (
  -- define columns that match the results of the sproc.
  -- You should also define a PK, and possibly other indexes
)

insert into #sprocResult exec proc1
```

(You can use a table valued variable as well.)

Comment: You can also make indexes on variable tables